# Apple AppStore policy change with respect to CoreLocation

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Posting this question on apple.stackexchange, [after 2 downvotes on SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002916/apple-appstore-policy-change-with-respect-to-corelocation/26015425#26015425)

I just noticed a change in Apple policy, 
Apple Store review guideline too seems to be updated, with this context about Location:

**Location data can only be used when directly relevant to the features and services provided by the App to the user or to support approved advertising uses**

Read more about CoreLocation [here](https://lmjabreu.com/post/ios-8-privacy-updates/#location):

A paragraph from the link mentioned, which sounds apt as well:
Applications must have a very good reason to access Location and make that clear to the user through the provided purpose description text or they will be rejected by the App Store team.

So the question is as follows, for using Location with **third party ad-network SDKs**:

If I access User's Location, and provide the Location to the ad-network, and while submitting my app for review, clearly mention the usage of Location is only for advertising, and that I'm fetching User's Location for serving geo-targeted ads?
An ad-network which access User's location by flag settings. In this case, I mention that Location is being accessed by third party ad-network SDK for serving geo-targeted ads.
Is it likely the app would get rejected?

If so, **(a)** is there any workaround, like mentioning anything specific/clearly in App Store review process?

Or (b)Location should NEVER be accessed for a third party network SDK?

If **(b)** is the case, then can anyone help decrypt Apple's so much encrypted message as stated above?

Comment: Are you sure there are any third party ad networks that provide geo-targeted ads? I hardly doubt you could just take the location data for ad purposes. It could be bound to be rejected!

Comment: Hi @JashJacob, yes, I wanted to know why Apple made a shift in their policy.
So lets say in a chat app, where the app uses User's location for its internal purpose, and also provides it to an ad-network.
From this setting, would it be good enough to state, that the Location is being fetched for advertising?

Answer (score 1):

My app went live with CoreLocation Manager settings(which doesn't fetch location by default).